# How to replace values outside of 95 percentile with NA in large dataset

Tags: r

I have a large dataset, df (~80,000 observations of 17 variables, 7 of which are actual readings).
I want a fast way to remove outliers.

How do I retain only 2.5% to 97.5% (95% range) of the original measurements, replacing anything outside of this range with NA?
I want this done on a column-wise basis, so that the whole row is not deleted if one of the variables is outside of its range.

I already tried:

```
df$var[df$var > quantile(df$var, 0.95, na.rm=TRUE)] <- NA
```

But this just seems to convert values greater than the range, whereas I want to remove lower than 2.5% and greater than 97.5%.

Comment: Can you please make this statement clearer: "I want this done on a column-wise basis, so that the whole row is not deleted if one of the variables is outside of its range.".. ?

Comment: I basically just want to perform this action for each column individually and not the whole dataset (i.e. I want to retain the values inside of the 95% range for var1, then do the same for var2 etc. without them affecting each other). Hope this helps

Comment: okay, so if you data frame has N rows, it should still have N rows after the operation, but values within each column will have approximately 5% of the values replaced with `NA`?

Comment: Yes exactly! :)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide a reproducible example. To keep the problem compact, maybe provide 10 values and screen for 25th and 75th percentile and show what your current code does and what your desired result should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

1. Create a simple function `rm_outliers()` that takes a vector x, and a threshold `a` (default=0.025), and returns the same vector `x` with values outside `a` and `1-a` replaced with NA
2. Apply the function to each of your target columns; lots of ways to do this, see various options below

```
rm_outliers <- function(x,a=0.025) {
  qs = quantile(x,probs=c(a, 1-a))
  x[!between(x,qs[1],qs[2])] <- NA
  x
}
```

2a.`data.table`: set your data to data.table, and apply to columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
cols = paste0("V",1:5)
setDT(data)[, (cols):=lapply(.SD, rm_outliers), .SDcols = cols]
```

2b. `baseR`:

```
cols = paste0("V",1:5)
data[,cols] <- lapply(cols, \(x) rm_outliers(data[[x]]))
```

2c (alternate data.table option)

```
setDT(data)
cols = paste0("V",1:5)
for(x in cols) set(data,j=x,value=rm_outliers(data[[x]]))
```

2d (`dplyr::mutate()` option):

```
dplyr::mutate(data, across(V1:V5, rm_outliers))
```

Output (same, regardless of 2a, 2b, 2c, 2d):

```
               V1          V2         V3         V4         V5
            <num>       <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>
   1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872 -0.5116037 -0.1503075  0.1965498
   2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  0.2369379 -0.3277571  0.6501132
   3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024 -0.5415892 -1.4481653  0.6710042
   4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  1.2192276 -0.6972846 -1.2841578
   5:  0.12928774          NA  0.1741359         NA         NA
  ---                                                         
 996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  1.0609662 -1.4284746 -0.8504180
 997:  1.07051604  0.25516476 -0.4455056  1.2674975  1.6244691
 998: -1.35110039  0.27744682 -0.4291802  1.2145058 -0.1266382
 999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  1.1890118 -0.6748559  1.2756020
1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  0.8342941  1.1210219  0.1794962
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
data = setNames(as.data.frame(
  lapply(1:5, \(i) rnorm(1000))
), paste0("V",1:5))
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks very much! I had to include na.rm=TRUE into the quantile part of rm_outliers function cause there was NA's in my df (just for anyone else who wants to use this). Ended up going with the dplyr option, thanks again, I appreciate the options